# Display the value from the formula ONLY if another cell has the value that I want

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've devised a formula that I want my cells to have, but I only want the value to show up if ANOTHER cell is populated with the value that I want.

My current formula is below:

```
=COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, "Brain")
```

However, this formula doesn't check whether or not the other cell has the value that I want to check for.

I put together a formula that I thought would check for whether or not the cell is populated:

```
=COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, "Brain", R21, "Brain")
```

Unfortunately, this formula doesn't work (it returns `#VALUE!`). I think it fails because R21 is already included in the `COUNTIFS`.

I also tried this similar formula, which also failed to work:

```
=COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, "Brain", R21:R21, "Brain")
```

I looked online and I found this possible solution:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Brain",R21)),"COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, 'Brain')","")
```

Unfortunately, this formula displays the text of the formula I want, and not the actual value of the formula.

Does anyone know how I could display the value from the formula ONLY if the cell I'm checking has the value that I want? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `"` surounding the `"COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, 'Brain')"` and it will act like the formula.: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Brain",R21)),COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, 'Brain'),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Brain",R21)),COUNTIFS($R$3:R21, 'Brain'),"")
```